Oracle's JRE runs on lower resolution
When I want to run a Java app, Jar, jnpl... with Oracle JRE for windows it looks like 32-bit programs, but with Eclipse Termurin JRE looks great.
(Java 8)
JAR running with Oracle's JRE
JAR running with Termurin JRE

I see no difference between those two screenshots other than the second screenshot has no text.

They use different fonts. Maybe this give you feeling about the resolution.

Look at the icon, for example

What research have you done regarding this? Perhaps this is a ClearType issue? The issues you indicate are subtle and could be due to a number of factors. Also, isn't Eclipse open source? So you could check the rendering code or libraries to see what they may use. You also don't ask a question, so we don't know what you are actually trying to learn or what problem you wish solved.

I want to use the Windows default icons

I think I have Java 8 32 bits, because on control panel says "Java (32 bits)", but I don't know how to get 64 bit version, because I downloaded 64 bits installer and it keeps installing that version
